Nginx Podman : 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
I'm setting up some podman containeurs in order to build my web app PHP for backend and vue js for frontend, with NGINX, and MYSQL with podman on a redhat 9 machine for the first time. After running podman-compose up --build command, I am getting an error in command prompt as below:
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
Structure:
dockerfile.php for php folder
dockerfile for vue js build
docker-compose.yaml to create all container
I'm not able to make my app work.
Can you see anything wrong ?
Dockerfile.php :
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Installer les dépendances requises, y compris git, unzip, et les bibliothèques pour l'extension zip PHP
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    git \
    unzip \
    libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd zip

# Installer Composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"


RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql


WORKDIR /var/www/html


docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: /var/www/starhub
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.php # Assure-toi que ce fichier existe et est configuré pour ton environnement PHP
    container_name: php-fpm-container
    volumes:
      - /var/www/starhub:/var/www:Z
    networks:
      - app-network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx-container
    volumes:
      - /var/www/starhub/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d # Assure-toi d'avoir les configurations de Nginx pour Symfony et Vue.js ici
      - /var/www/starhub:/var/www/starhub:ro
        #      - /var/www/azura-network:/var/www/azura-network:ro
      - /var/www/azura-network:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
      - azura
    networks:
      - app-network

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql-container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: AzuraLocalHost
      MYSQL_DATABASE: localdbazura
      MYSQL_USER: Azura
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Azura
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app-network

  azura:
    build:
      context: /var/www/azura-network
      dockerfile: Dockerfile # Assure-toi que ce Dockerfile est configuré pour construire ton application Vue.js
    container_name: azura_vuejs
    volumes:
      - /var/www/azura-network:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mysql-data:




Dockerfile (frontend vue js)
# Étape 1: Définir l'image de base pour la construction de l'application
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage

# Définir le répertoire de travail dans le conteneur
WORKDIR /app

# Copier les fichiers 'package.json' et 'yarn.lock' dans le répertoire de travail
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

# Installer Vue CLI globalement
RUN yarn global add @vue/cli

# Installer les dépendances du projet
RUN yarn install

# Copier le reste des fichiers du projet dans le répertoire de travail
COPY . .

# Construire l'application pour la production
RUN yarn run build


Nginx configuration file :
/var/www/starhub/nginx/default.conf
server {
    server_name api.back-azura.local;
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/starhub/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000; # Assure-toi que cette adresse correspond à ton service PHP-FPM
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }

    # Cette section est utilisée pour bloquer l'accès direct aux fichiers PHP qui ne sont pas l'index
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/starhub_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/starhub_access.log;
}


/var/www/starhub/nginx/frontend.conf
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name frontend.local; # Utilise un nom de domaine ou localhost
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/dist/;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  location / {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}



podman logs
[root@localhost nginx]# podman logs nginx-container 
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2024/04/13 15:30:04 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2024/04/13 15:30:04 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.4
2024/04/13 15:30:04 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14) 
2024/04/13 15:30:04 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.x86_64
2024/04/13 15:30:04 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2024/04/13 15:30:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2024/04/13 15:30:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 15
2024/04/13 15:30:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 16
2024/04/13 15:30:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 17
2024/04/13 15:30:04 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 18


I have try to debug changing configuration files, simplifed the initial configuration at strict minimum.
Any idea ?
Thanks
